# The largest connected component of a random subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, randomness, random-graphs

Let a graph on $|V|$ vertices and $|E|$ edges. We randomly sample $s= c \cdot \frac{|V|}{{d_{\text{av}}}}$ vertices, without replacement, where $d_{\text{av}}$ is the average degree of $G$ and $c$ is some big constant. Let $G'$ be the subgraph induced by these $s$ vertices.

What is the size of the largest connected component of $G'$?

I'm tempted to say $O(\log(s))$, under a mild assumption like |E| = o(|V|^2). Some intuition comes from the fact that the probability of 2 vertices in $G'$ being friends is $\sim \frac{E}{V^2} = \frac{{d_{\text{av}}}}{|V|}=1/s$; if $G'$ was an Erdős–Rényi then, it would be below the giant component threshold. Obviously, the edges in $G'$ are not independent, so the result does not immediately hold.

Examples where the O(log(s)) claim is true: star, cycle graph, union of cliques of size o(n).

Any ideas?

Comment: By "without replacement" of the vertices, what happens to the edges that connect to non chosen vertices?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. $G'$ sits on the vertices selected, and the edges of $G'$ are only the ones between the induced vertices.

Comment: Ok, and what is the quantity $d_{av}$?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, it's the average degree.

Comment: Why does not $c=d_{av}$ force $G'=G$?

Comment: Turns out that this has been recently proven for $s = (1-\epsilon)\cdot \frac{n}{d_{\max}}$, which is really cool. The result can be found under Theorem 1 here http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5731.pdf

Comment: I don't understand why you say the $O(\log s)$ bound is true for stars. Average degree is $2$, set $c = 1/50$ so $s = n/100$. Then the random selection will pick the root with probability $1/100$, in which case the size of the component is $s$. So expected size of the largest component is at least $s/100$, no?